# AWS JAVA BeanStalk - What environmet is running the app

Tags: java, spring-mvc, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

There's a way to know in my app if it's running at a specific beanstalk envinroment?

I am using Java with SPRING MVC and have access to AWS SDK.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to resolve.

In AWS Management Console is possible to set environment parameters.

So I set this parameters on the different envinroments and simple check in my java app:

```
System.getProperty("param1")
```

I don't know if that's a better way, but for me solves now.

Thanks.